# Html5 Banner File Size

Tags: html, filesize, banner

next month google will stop flash ads automatically, so we got a lot of requests to remake our flash banners in html.

The IAB made 2013  some guidelines for html5 banners. The maximum file size should be 100kb..

We're using 2 ways to publish our banners. One is with google doubleclick and the other one is direct publishing on websites.

We got no problem with doubleklick, because they say, that the initial load should be under 100kb and the rest could be loaded after that.

But the publishers for the direct publishing are saying, that the whole banner (all files which are used and compressed as a zip) should be max. 100kb.

Our client has got some designing guidelines, so we have to include the font (which contains 4 formats and 2 font types). But even the font has 400kb.

So the only way we have at the moment is, to convert the text into pictures, to keep the filesize down.. But this isn't the concept of html5...

DOes someone of you got a solution for that problem ?? :O

Thanks

Comment: can you load your fonts dynamically with js?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto — No. Initial vs total load is already addressed in the question.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto no, i cant .... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use doubleClick, because dealing with publisher directly will make you crazy. They don't know about polite loading and are very strict on the file sizes, but when you use doubleClick you can use Polite load Options.

About the typefaces, if you want to put some copies on the website it is better to generate png for that and optimize those png with software like imageOptim.

This way each Copy will be around 1Kb.

But the whole webfont is around 100KB which does not make sence to add in one banner.

Beside first check available free webfonts that you can use without adding any extra weight on the banner.

Answer (score 0):

About the webfonts, you could use Google Fonts and limit by char used.
For instance, if the text is "Hello" only 4 chars is included (H e l o).

And I agree with [Majid Kalkatechi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353269/majid-kalkatechi), use DFP and Polite loading.

Answer (score 0):

With DoubleClick you will need to host your fonts on https, they won't be included in the file size limit. They might impact performance of the ad unit, loading in later, which will mean webfonts will show temporarily.

Why are you using fonts and not images? Are the ads using dynamic text? If not use images. Normally keeping an ad under 100kb shouldn't be a problem